# JSF 2.2 How to escape text "${value}"

Tags: jsf, escaping, el

I try to print out some text

```
<h:outputText value="The template is ${user}/${age}"/>
```

But the output is like this

> The template is /

${user} and ${age} were evaulated...

I tried using

```
&#36;&#123;user&#125;
```

But they still get evaulated.

Comment: I tried the solution from the other post..and the result is the same...

When I put "\${user}", the output show the whole thing "\${user}"

When I put "&#36;{user}", the whole string was evaluated and show "[empty]"

Does JQuery affect this?

Comment: At the end, I made it work without using "<h:outputText>" and simply put the text on the xhtml file with the backslash before the dollar sign.

In the h:outputText, I tried both escape=true and escape=false, neither produce the result I wanted.